# Photoshop: How to paint black and white image to purple and yellow

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to make my black and white image purple and yellow. Turn all black colors to purple, all white to yellow and all grey shades to proportion of purple and yellow the same as black and white in original image. Is there a way I can do this in photoshop?